# UIGestureRecognizer on transformed layer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, cabasicanimation

I'm working on and iPhone app, and have an issue with a gesture recognizer.

I've added an UITapGestureRecognizer on a view, then I transform the layer related to this view with CABasicAnimation. After this transformation, the gesture recognizer only works in the area occupied by the view before the transformation.

Hope this little description of my problem is understandable..

Here is some code :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myViewTapped:)];
[self.myView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

CABasicAnimation * animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]];
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: - 100]];
[animation setDuration:.3];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:.55 :-0.25 :.30 :1.4]];
animation.additive = YES;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[self.myView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

How can I handle this issue ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You are animating only the graphical part of the view (the CALayer), not the part responsable for user interaction (the UIView itself).
Your code move the layer and made it been drown elsewhere, but don't change the frame (or the bound+center).

You have 3 option (well maybe more, just I can think of these 3):

1) use the UIView-based animations `[UIView animation...]`

2) struct with you code but also relocare the view after the animation take place (but this may rise issues cause your layer will be moved also).

3) use your animation but put the gesture recognizer on a parent (bigger) view and then check the events there...

Comment: Thank you for your help,
I can't use UIView based animations, because I have to use a custom easing curve (do you know a way to do this ?)

I finally found this solution : 
I set the ViewController as delegate of the CABasicAnimation, removed the additive property, then in the animationDidStop method, I added this line of code : 
    self.bottomView.layer.position = CGPointMake(self.bottomView.layer.position.x,[((NSNumber *)((CABasicAnimation *)anim).toValue) floatValue]);

— I'm aware of better solution if someone has one